# 360º degree camera in three.js

Tags: camera, three.js, virtual-reality, panoramas, 360-virtual-reality

Does anyone know how to create a 360º camera in three.js?

I'm trying to render the entire scene as a 360º panorama like you would with a go pro 360 rig.

I'm trying to recreate a panorama by arranging several screens in a circle and stretch a threejs window across all the screens.

For this I need a very wide window that has a tree.js camera that captures the entire scene in 360º

Is this possible?

Comment: here there. Did you ever get this working in realtime? what was the performance like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible, as it was already implemented: https://github.com/spite/THREE.CubemapToEquirectangular

That library will just export snapshots as png, but looking at the code it should be possible to integrate the same method it uses into realtime-rendering if you want to...

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting!

Comment: Doesnt seem to work in threejs 103. There are a number of new changes to cubeCamera and THREE.WebGLRenderTargetCube (no longer called this, and you need to be careful of shadows and clearing buffers).

Answer (score 3):

You can't represent a 360-degree view with a conventional view matrix. You need to render to a set of textures (e.g. the six faces of a cube)  then combine them into a 360 degree mapping such as equirectangular.